# How to get reactions count for all posts on public page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm stuck with one thing.

How can I get reactions count for public page?

For example I have a page with 100 posts, each post have 10 reactions.
Which query I should run to get something like that:

```
{
    "reactions_count": 1000
}
```

I've found only one way to do it with reactions per post with this query:

```
/feed?fields=reactions.summary(total_count).limit(0)
```

But if the page has a large amount of posts it would be quite hard to get total reactions count for all posts.

Thanks!

Comment: This is not directly available. Going through all posts would be your only option - but it is not a very realistic one, because performance issues aside, the API tends to leave out stuff the further you go back. // And my personal opinion, this sounds like a rather nonsense metric to me anyway; I can’t see what actual value it would have.

Comment: Yeah, I also think there is no way, but I just need someone else opinion.
This metric is quite useful for me. But it seems I'll go without it.

Thanks for answer.